# getting NuGet to work both with whole solution and individual projects included in it

Tags: git, msbuild, jenkins, solution, csproj

I have a solution with a few projects in it. All but one are class library projects, used in several solutions, included as git submodules, and don't have a .sln file, just a .csproj and .cs sources.

something like this (one line, one repository)

```
TheProgram: .sln, exe.csproj, .nuget/NuGet.{config,targets}, packages.config, .cs files
  submodule-0: sub-n.csproj, packages.config, and some .cs files
  submodules-1 to n: as above
```

When compiling the whole solution, everything works nicely - nuget.exe gets downloaded if needed, packages get installed and it just works.

Cloning single subproject that uses nuget packages, then using msbuild to build it fails. It can't find `nuget.targets`. Looking at the csproj it seems to be because of these lines:

```
<SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\..\</SolutionDir>
...
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

Having a project reference a path starting with `..\..\` feels wrong to me, but this is what nuget generates and i have very limited experience hand writing msbuild scripts.

Reason i'd like this to work is jenkins, which built any part of the solution(s) after push quite nicely, when i was not using any nuget packages.

I can see a few ways to make this work, for example could add nuget dir to each submodule and use that if not compiled as part of solution,  or add some BeforeBuild command line to each csproj, or add a .sln to each submodule. None of those feels quite right.

Am I doing something horribly wrong, and when i stop doing that everything will just work?

If not, has someone solved similar problem in a way that's not too ugly to share, or should I just study msbuild a bit and do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a nuget.config to each project that specifies an external location as the repository.

```
<configuration>
 <config>
     <add key="repositoryPath" value="c:\nuget" />
 </config>
 <packageSources>
     <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
 </packageSources>
 <activePackageSource>
     <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
 </activePackageSource>
 <packageRestore>
     <add key="enabled" value="true" />
 </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by defining the `SolutionDir` property in relation to the `MSBuildProjectDirectory` property:

```
<SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\</SolutionDir>
```

Comment: At the moment not doing any .net development, and don't have visual studio (or windows) installed, so I can't verify this working. Will accept as answer if/when I get the chance to verify it works for me too.